# Command is not defined exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, command

I created a command with Artisan

```
$ php artisan command:make NeighborhoodCommand
```

This created the file `app/commands/NeighborhoodCommand.php`

Snippet of the code. I modified the `name` value and filled in the `fire()` function

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class NeighborhoodCommand extends Command {

    protected $name = 'neighborhood';

    public function fire()
    {
        // my code
    }
}
```

But then when I try to run the command with

```
$ php artisan neighborhood
```

I get this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Command "neighborhood" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Laravel 5.5+**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#registering-commands

If you'd like, you can continue manually registering your commands. But L5.5 gives you the option to lazy load them. If you are upgrading from an older version add this method to your Kernel:

```
/**
 * Register the commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

---

**Laravel 5**

http://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#registering-commands

Edit your `app/Console/Kernel.php` file and add your command to the `$commands` array:

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\NeighborhoodCommand::class,
];
```

---

**Laravel 4**

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#registering-commands

Add this line to `app/start/artisan.php`:

```
Artisan::add(new NeighborhoodCommand);
```

Comment: Plus for being humble and a good answer. Happened to me 1000 times!

Comment: Laravel 5.5+ PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare App\Console\Kernel::commands()

Answer (score 2):

By changing ***signature*** in your command class to your ***commandName***. 
change

```
protected $signature = 'command:name';
```

TO

```
protected $signature = 'NeighborhoodCommand';
```

Now try to run

```
$ php artisan NeighborhoodCommand
```

It works for me.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560384)

Answer (score 2):

if none of the above work for you you might want to try to  `composer dumpautoload` which fixed for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case

I tried all the above and I would still get the "Command is not defined" message (even after a composer dumpautoload). This was before I embarrassingly realised my command file name was not binding the Command Class name.

I had

Filename : CommandThatDoes**This**.php

Class: CommandThatDoes**That**

Ran a composer dumpautoload just after and all was fine.

> note: this would have never happened if I created the command properly, using the php artisan make:command. I ended up in this situation because I duplicated an existing command.

Answer (score 0):

you should also note, that if you fail to put in the proper value to $signature, you will get the same error