# Laravel 5.8 custom command not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-artisan

I have created a custom command using artisan:

> php artisan make:command resetNegotiations

Than deleted cache with:

> php artisan cache:clear

But if I try to run: *php artisan ResetNegotiations* I got the error:

> Command "ResetNegotiations" is not defined.

The file *ResetNegotiations.php* exists in *app/Console/Commands*

I have found similar questions:
- [Command is not defined exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462266/command-is-not-defined-exception) but it not fixed mine.

I have updated the kernel as https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#registering-commands in app/Console/Kernel.php  but... nothing. The same error also after cache rebuilt.

**kernel.php**

```
 ....
 protected $commands = [
    Commands\ResetNegotiations::class,
    //
];
```

What I'm missing?

This is the command:

```
<?php
  namespace App\Console\Commands;
  use Illuminate\Console\Command;

   class resetNegotiations extends Command{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'command:name';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    //

    mail("######@#####.it", "Scheduledartsan ", "Command test");

}
```

}

Comment: You should use camelcasing otherwise the file will not be autoloaded properly. So rename the class to `ResetNegotiations` and the file to `ResetNegotiations.php`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the class name, class file and kernel using the uppercase. Flushed the cache but the command artisan list show all commands but mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protected $signature = 'command:name';` is what you use to call the command in artisan. just change the signature to `protected $signature = 'resetNegotiations';` if you want to use that. The artisan command you posted should work after the change.